# How to modify hidden fields in Cakephp4 using javascript?

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to fetch user's geo location on a form submit. The javascript code I've written is modifying the value of the hidden location field

form

```
<?= $this->Form->control('location1', ['type' => 'text', 'value'=> "", 'id'=>'location', 'label'=>false]); ?>
```

script

```
    function DoSubmit(){

        event.preventDefault();
        const success = (position) => {
            console.log(position);
            document.getElementById("location").value ='set latitude and longitude here';
        };
        const error = () =>{
            const position = "Unable to get your location";
            document.getElementById("location").value = 0;
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        event.currentTarget.submit();
      return true;
    }
```

controller

```
public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Security');
    }
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Security->setConfig('validatePost', false);
    }
```

but Cakephp is not submitting the value. The location field remains blank. What should I do?

I suspected it would be the security or the form-protection preventing the change so I've tried [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/security.html#form-tampering-prevention:%7E:text=Configuring%20the%20security%20component%20is%20generally%20done%20in%20the%20controller%E2%80%99s%20initialize%20or%20beforeFilter()%20callbacks%3A) to prevent security component. But it does not have any effect.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your JS is in fact updating the value in the location input? Have you used browser tools to confirm that the data you expect to be sent is being sent?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed, Javascript is updating the value of location. But not submitting. I've tried switching off validation using FormProtectionComponent but even that is not working.

Comment: To be clear, I'm asking what points you have inspected to see the data. You should be able to see what the browser is sending as well as what your Cake app is receiving, to isolate where the problem lies. If you had something that showed us exactly what's being sent from the browser, for example, we might see why you're not getting what you expect in Cake.

Comment: For example, in Firefox, you can use Ctrl-Shift-E to open the Network Monitor. Submit your form, click the request that generates, and click the Request tab to see the data that got sent.